# How to use PHP Print function to print a html tag containing PHP code?

Tags: php

I want to do something in PHP like:
`<?php Print '<h1> <?php echo "Hello"; ?> </h1>' ?>`
How can I do that? (I want the output to be `Hello` in browser, NOT `<h1> <?php echo "Hello"; ?> </h1>` in browser)

Comment: Why not to print it this way: `<?= '<?php Print \'<h1> <?php echo "Hello"; ?> </h1>\' ?>'` ?

Comment: Your code works fine and outputs `<h1> <?php echo "Hello"; ?> </h1>` if you need to escape for HTML, you can use for example htmlentities:  `<?php print htmlentities('<h1> <?php echo "Hello"; ?> </h1>') ?>`

Answer (score 0):

You just do :

```
<h1><?php echo ‘Hello’;?></h1>
```

Or

```
<?php echo ‘<h1>Hello</h1>‘; ?>
```